# Use a name other than MANIFEST.in for Distutils manifest template

Tags: python, distutils

In the Python [documentation for distribution](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute), it is stated that the manifest template is named `MANIFEST.in` by *default*. It then doesn't appear to state anything about how to change that default.

For the sake of a mixed language project, I'd like to name `MANIFEST.in` something more like `PYTHON-MANIFEST.in` or some such to avoid the mental load on developers who need to know what belongs to what language (and we cannot just put the Python subproject into a subdirectory as it needs access to umbrella project items at root).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command-line help for the Distutils `sdist` command has the answer:

```
$ python3 ./setup.py sdist --help
[…]
Options for 'sdist' command:
  --template (-t)        name of manifest template file [default: MANIFEST.in]
[…]
```

So you can name your “[manifest template](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest)” file any name you like, and then **specify the template filename with the `template` option** for `sdist`.

I could not find the answer in the Distutils documentation, which really needs some dedicated improvement and maintenance.

Comment: This does not seem to exist anymore, tested on distutils 3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

The above answer gave me a place to look and find a way to do this programmatically.

When using `setuptools` it's possible to simply reassign the variable that's used to find the manifest template:

```python
setuptools.command.egg_info.manifest_maker.template = 'your-manifest-template-here.in'
```

I imagine that a similar thing would be possible with pure `distutils` by deriving from `distutils.command.sdist.sdist` and changing what `self.template` is assigned to in an overridden `finalize_options` (and further, of course, assigning this as your custom `sdist` command).

Comment: does not exist anymore on distutils 3.6.5